# Provisioning scripts - technical info

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm looking to integrate provisioning scripts in the implementation process of my new servers.

I couldn't find any info regarding how to write those scripts or some examples.

I was looking at that page:
http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/topic/provisioning-scripts

Please advice,

TIA,
Gili

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have several questions here.

> how to write those scripts

It can be any executable program, not necessarily a shell script -- it could be a Javascript or Python program or even a binary. What it does is completely up to you.

> One thing it does not do is RUN

Firstly, for the script (or program) to run automatically it must be downloaded using the HTTPS protocol, which is not the case in your example (`http://10digits.us/ops/test1.sh`). To quote the SoftLayer documentation article you link to:

> > scripts associated with an HTTP URL are downloaded to the device and must be **manually executed** on the device[...] Scripts associated with an HTTPS URL are downloaded and executed.

(Emphasis mine).

Secondly, the provisioning program (script) only runs once, when the machine is provisioned. It does *not* run when you restart or power on an existing machine.

> where can I see a log of what/why provisioning process did or failed

The provisioning process does not log any output or result of executing your provisioning script or program. It is the responsibility of your script to log what's happening when it runs. The only notification you will get from SoftLayer would be when it fails to download the script (program) from the configured URL.

---

There's also an [informative post here](http://bodenr.blogspot.com/2014/04/giving-your-softlayer-servers.html) that provides additional details.